# Decoding JSON from web service returns JSON error syntax

Tags: php, json

I have a small PHP script that is supposed to get all the values from a web service´s JSON. But after decoding it, I keep getting error 4.

```
$url_de = "http://ws-old.parlament.ch/factions?format=json&lang=de&pretty=true";    
$jsonObject = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_de));
```

The string $url_de has the URL of website´s JSON file that contains the following when viewed in a browser:

```
[
 {
"name": "Liberale Fraktion",
"shortName": "Fraktion L",
"code": "FRA_7_",
"abbreviation": "L",
"id": 7,
"updated": "2015-08-31T08:53:40Z"
 },
  {
    "name": "Sozialdemokratische Fraktion",
    "shortName": "Fraktion S",
    "code": "FRA_2_",
    "abbreviation": "S",
    "id": 2,
    "updated": "2015-08-24T15:28:11Z",
    "hasMorePages": false
  }
]
```

When using var_dump I keep getting NULL. Any ideas how to fix it? I would like to output certain keys and their values.

EDIT: This is the HTML output when using var_dump [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRX42.png)
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210718/discussion-on-question-by-dnyx-decoding-json-from-web-service-returns-json-error).

Answer (score 2):

I've emulated your Webservice call that working on the web browser with PHP curl and it works fine for me, Hopes it will work for you also.

**Note** You'll not require some of the **Headers** so you can discard them. The minimum you need like this example https://3v4l.org/QaUTl

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ws-old.parlament.ch/factions?format=json&lang=de&pretty=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en-IN;q=0.7';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: SessionId=ybsj42455jmgxy55ujqn4c45; BIGipServerpool_frontend_ext_prod=210882826.20480.0000; PD_WebServices_Culture=de; TS011b62d7=0105a873d69ab2bf15b10d359e436b495a612d9693e8d00bd58e025621fb968b99223e473d2fe8154f4ff4acea8109792c30c6a2eb429a3297a4304e770889c54c3f621f7e330185c6d1c4c58523f82f5f168cf4a228fac9d6fb500eb6007c20da3a2f59aa21125d29b5c2c0e2eb2436b88eb5df00';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
print '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($result));
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: this much is enough: https://3v4l.org/QaUTl (checked via phpfiddle and i think good to go)

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie thanks you sir, I'm going to edit it

Comment: don't edit it. Just add my example link in your answer. because your answer is going to be helpful for others in different different scenario.

Comment: Okay I'll do, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
$url = 'http://ws-old.parlament.ch/factions/1?format=json&lang=de';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36");

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$jsonObject = json_decode($data);
```